# Why is 嘘 used to represent the word うそ?

Tags: kanji

Why is 嘘 used to represent the word うそ? To my knowledge, 嘘 in Chinese doesn't have the meaning *to lie*; most of the definitions in the Kangxi Dictionary for instance are related to something like *to breath out slowly*. I came across two possible leads:

1. Derived from 虚 (*empty* > *lie*, e.g. 虚言). Japanese Wiktionary notes 虚言 being equivalent to 嘘言, but it seems to me 嘘言 is a Japanese-only spelling.
2. Used as a variant form of 譃 (also written as  or 謣). Wiktionary even glosses 譃 with a kun'yomi of うそ, but I haven't found any dictionaries that establishes this variant relation.

Wondering if anyone is able to provide a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it was a common misuse, rather than a (more officially accepted) variant, and the misuse became the dominant way to write the word eventually.

[誤用便覧](https://dl.ndl.go.jp/pid/862888/1/51), a Meiji-period reference book, says it's a misuse, precisely because of the Chinese origin you described. It also suggests that the misuse comes from folk etymology (of understanding 口 as "language", if I may speculate).

> この字に「うそ」という義はなく、正しくは「譃」（音はク若しくはコにしてキョに非ず）とすべきであるが、併し口扁に虛の字形から意味をとつて、これを「うそ」と訓ずるやうになつたのである。

It looks like [Akutagawa Ryunosuke](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/1172662?page=54) and [Mori Ogai](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/962491?page=154), both Meiji-period authors, used 譃 for *uso* (although they used 嘘, too). [温故知新書](https://dl.ndl.go.jp/pid/2497266/1/19), a 1484 dictionary (originally), included 譃 for *uso* without mentioning 嘘. This is not to say 嘘 for *uso* was a later invention, but these authors might have preferred 譃 because the other character was considered misuse.

Comment: `It also suggests that the misuse comes from folk etymology (of understanding 口 as "language", if I may speculate).` Just something to note: there are some variant characters where the semantic components 口 (often relating actions done with the mouth) and 言 (often relating to speech) are interchanged. For example, consider that 喧 (orig. to be in an uproar) and 嘩 (orig. loud and unpleasant noise) have variant forms 諠 and 譁 respectively.

Comment: Yes, this one seems like a reasonable one as far as folk etymology goes, although it doesn't explain the difference in the on'yomi pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

This is speculation, as I have not yet found a source that states this.

I suspect the key semantic connection between the Chinese and Japanese uses of this kanji might lie in the Chinese sense of *"to praise, to flatter"*, as we see in sense #3 [in this Chinese dictionary entry](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E5%99%93#gyjs).  This seems to be an outgrowth of the *"to blow, to puff"* sense -- consider also English *"to [puff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puff#English:_flatter) someone up"*, another way of saying *"to flatter someone"*.  Consider also the English *"to [blow smoke](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow_smoke)"*, another way of saying *"to lie"*, or even just *"to [blow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow#English:_brag)"*, a now-dated way of saying *"to brag"*.

- *"to blow, to puff"*
    ↓
- *"to puff someone up: to praise or flatter someone"*
    ↓
  then, presumably from ideas of specifically **false praise**:
    ↓
- *"to lie, to tell an untruth"*

I do see in various Japanese kanji dictionaries that 嘘 is also used to spell 嘘【ふ】く (such as [the ふく entry at Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8F#:%7E:text=exhale); if the anchor doesn't take you to the right section, search that page for the 嘘 kanji), cognate with 吹【ふ】く *"to blow"*, suggesting that the Japanese senses are not entirely disconnected from the original Chinese.  The semantic overlaps in English between "puff; blow" and "brag; lie" also suggest that the basic idea of "blowing, puffing" might not be too far removed from the idea of "telling an untruth", even across cultures.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning you cite accords well with what my 角川漢和辞典, presents:

①ふく（吹く）。うそぶく。はく。息を長く吐く。

②ああ。ため息のことば

＜国訓＞うそ。いつわり。

Note how the dictionary is indicating that this meaning of "lie" is specifically a Japanese use of the kanji.

In the first definition うそぶく can mean to "roar", "howl", "boast" and several of meanings of a similar nature.

It would seem that うそぶく is semantically similar to lying along with perhaps a etymological tie also (though my dictionary doesn't go into that).  Thus, the kanji acquires a secondary meaning of "to lie" in Japanese.

Comment: Beat me to it by minutes! 